# Saving attachments to database: blob vs path reference

Tags: mysql, database, blob

I am in a process of designing a system where one can create an entry and then add attachments to that entry, which is then saved into a database.  However I am of two minds on how to implement the attachment handling.

I am battling between two approaches:

1. Save the attachments to the database directly as blob field type
2. Save to the database the directory path into the file and save the actual file to the server

Now as far as I can see both of these approaches has pros and cons.

1st approach would keep all the data in the same place so I can easily move it elsewhere if I want to.  Also it keeps things consistent as far as "where is the data" guestion is concerned.  On the other hand I have heard that saving things like that is very resource hog and the database size will grow extensively.

2nd approach would allow the database to keep to the easily managed data fields like text and numbers while the more heavier stuff is on the server.  This would also allow a more direct access to files if necessary.  On the other hand the data is seperated and more difficult to keep track of and would also need to introduce file system access in order to retrieve the said files.

I am leaning towards the number 1 approach but to this end I am hoping an answer to the following:

> How would saving attachments directly to database impact on the database size and
>   application performance?

Comment: "Don't ever" is a serious overstatement padiwan

Comment: @Sam Why?  Please I would like to hear some reasoning as I have seen applications that do save files directly to database so obviously someone thought it was a good idea.

Comment: @Grietom just because someone did it, it doesn't mean it was a good idea

Comment: Doesn't mean it was a bad idea either!

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not saying because it was done it was a bad idea i'm saying it was a bad idea because of the points mentioned. You are confirming the consequent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't store documents as blobs in the database. Store paths. RDBMS is not a document store. MySQL is not designed for this purpose and storing documents inside MySQL will make the database size unnecessarily huge and data retrieval almost impossible, taking backups will take a very long time and if something happens to your database all your files go with it. File store is almost always a better choice for file storage than a RDBMS.

Comment: OTOH, tt might make the database *necessarily* huge! And if something happens to your filestore, it takes your files with it. There may be credible arguments in your favour, but I don't think these are them.

Comment: @Strawberry haha  yes couple of videos stored as blobs will do

Comment: @Strawberry filestores like s3 with hundreds of backup distributions are hardly ever going to fail whereas harddisk failure on an EBS is something very common. Moreover, the price of EBS is much more for I/O than S3 for example. If you think I'm not making a good case, answer with your points. I'd love to learn more about it.

Comment: I'm wondering if neither of you know if someone has made any studies as to how large and how slow the database would become when certain amount and size of files are stored?

Comment: I can't point you to a study but I'm working on a project with 1 TB of data and MySQL works fine. If the db is designed correctly performance does not change with size (given that it has the resources and RAM to utilize). Concurrency though is totally a different subject.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem, I think the approach I take is depending on the type of attachment that is needed
In my case what I did is open the attachment which is mostly text and simply place the data as in in the DB (instead of the DB simply storing the attachment)

This allows me to look also inside the content in an easy way (of course this relates to the number of updates that you expect)

Comment: Well in my case the attachment can be pretty much anything: pdf, screenshot,office document, plain text etc.  Basically a file which always adds a new level of complexity.